# How to compose custom tags in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm not new to ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, but I don't know how to achieve this.

In React, I can create components very easily, and I can compose them easily too.

For example, let's say I want to have a `tabs` component that accepts a list of `tab` component as its children. I want to be able to write something like this in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages:

```
<tabs>
    <tab title="Base info">
        <partial name="BaseInfo" />
    </tab>
    <tab title="Password">
        <partial name="Password" />
    </tab>
    <tab title="Profile picture">
        <partial name="Picture" />
    </tab>
</tabs>
```

Please note that `tabs` and `tab` tags are both custom tags.

How can I do this in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Comment: Isn't [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-5.0) what you are looking for?

Comment: Maybe you are talking about Partial Views? Its not very clear what are you asking....

Comment: does your project support Blazor?

Comment: @HadiR., no I'm not using Blazor.

Comment: @JohnDoe, I'll read that.

Comment: So then use a partial view that accepts the desired model for rendering the Tabs you want.

Comment: @HadiR., I'm not use if you understood the question. As you can see I want to have custom tags with nested children. That's not possible in partial views. How do you do that in partial views?